# Date format for Node.js, Sequelize, mysql and Vue

Tags: node.js, vue.js, orm, format, sequelize.js

I'm working on internal system for one company in Slovakia. I created API in node.js (express.js server) and I'm using Sequelize to query mysql.
On frontend I have Vue with Vuetify.

Problem is that every single Date is in ISO format (YYYY-MM-DD). In my country, we are using different date formant (DD-MM-YYYY). When I had meeting with CEO of that company, for who I'm making this app told me, that there are many older guys without english knowledge and for them ISO format could be hard.

I am new to Vue and also Node, basically this is my first programming job so please help me with this problem.

Here is my Vue code:

```
 <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4">
        <v-menu color="orange lighten-2 white--text"
          ref="datePicker"
          v-model="datePicker"
          :close-on-content-click="false"
          transition="scale-transition"
          offset-y
          min-width="auto"
        >
          <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
            <v-text-field color="orange lighten-2 white--text"
              v-model="dateOfDiscovery"
              label="Dátum zistenia"
              append-icon="mdi-calendar"
              required
              v-on="on"
              v-bind="attrs"
            ></v-text-field>
          </template>
          <v-date-picker color="orange lighten-2 white--text"
            v-model="dateOfDiscovery"
            @change="datePicker = false"
          >
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
          </v-date-picker>
        </v-menu>
      </v-col>
```

And here is my Node code:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
const Case = sequelize.define('Case', {
    caseName: DataTypes.STRING,
    constructionSite: DataTypes.STRING,
    createdBy: DataTypes.STRING,
    dateOfDiscovery: DataTypes.DATEONLY,
    dateOfRemoval: DataTypes.DATEONLY,
    responsible: DataTypes.STRING,
    howManyDiscoveries: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    placeOfDiscovery: DataTypes.STRING,
    text: DataTypes.TEXT,
    sanction: DataTypes.STRING,
    forCompany: DataTypes.STRING,
})
return Case
```

}

How can I change format of both, vue and node to correspond with my requirements?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

You can use momentJs library from your Vue application to format date
https://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use [Moment.JS](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) for this use case.

For example, changing from YYYY MM DD format to YYYY DD MM:

```
const moment = require('moment')
moment("2020-11-10").format("YYYY DD MM")
```

Comment: Am I able to use it where I define how my Case will look like and?
`moment(dateOfDiscovery)format('DD MM YYYY)`

Comment: you missed a `.` there, should be `moment(dateOfDiscovery).format('DD MM YYYY)`

Comment: Yeah I see, thank you!.. and now whenever I create new case, in DB it should be in this new format, right?

Comment: can't answer that question because I am not sure how you store it to the DB. But I believe what you just need to make sure it's on how you display it in the front, and whatever date format that you store in the DB, you can reformat it in the frontend using moment

Comment: You are right, for me it doesn't matter how I store data, only frontend needs to be formated..
I found this for Vue, it is correct usage? 

`<v-date-picker v-model="dateOfDiscovery" @change="datePicker = false" :format="customFormatter">`
And script: 
`customFormatter(date) {
      return moment(date).format('DD MMMM YYYY');
    }`

Comment: Before using `momentjs`, you should read Project Status section here https://momentjs.com/docs/ and consider their suggestions.  `"In most cases, you should not choose Moment for new projects. However there are some possible reasons you might want to keep using it."`

Comment: @maiiKy yes that should be the proper usage